# data structure reshaping in python (opt. with pandas)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am new to python and have encountered the need to do some "data reshaping".

I have a list of objects which all are the same type of a specific `namedtuple` .

I have the following knowledge of the values in the named fields of those objects:

Two of their fields (say x and y) include values which might repeat their combination at most twice and a third variable (say c) will always have one of two possible values (say "Black" and "White") and the combination of all three will always be unique.

i.e. I can have either or both T(x=1,y=1,c='BLACK', more field) and T(x=1,y=1,c='White', more field) in the list but it will never have two items such that they are the same on x y and c.

I want to reorganize them so that I have a list with a single (named)tuple per x,y combination in the original list and the original items will be assigned to  attributes named black and white.

so that 
if the original list was

```
orig=[T(x=1,y=1,c='Black',d=1),T(x=1,y=1,c='White',d=2),
 T(x=1,y=2,c='White',d=3),
 T(x=3,y=1,c='Black',d=4)]
```

it will be transformed to

```
target=[T2(x=1,y=1,black=T(x=1,y=1,c='Black',d=1),white=T(x=1,y=1,c='White',d=2)),
 T2(x=1,y=2,black=None,white=T(x=1,y=2,c='White',d=3)),
 T2(x=3,y=1,black=T(x=3,y=1,c='Black',d=4),white=None)
```

]

of course the original list is not guarantied to be ordered by the x and y values.

it is also important to say that the T named touples should remain the same instances in the second data structure such that for example if someone would assign `orig[0].d=5` then `target[0].black.d` would change accordingly.

I would be interested to know both if there is a way to do this using only python without any fancy libraries but also from some reading i have done about `pandas` I am guessing that it might also be very helpful and I would also like to know if a good solution exists that uses pandas.

Comment: Whats T and T2 ?

Comment: just names for the named tuples.